# Error while uploading File to S3 from Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, files, http, aws

I am using the below code to upload file to Amazon S3 from Apex class.

```
public void uploadToAmazonS3 () {
    String filename = this.record.File_Name__c;
    String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob);
    String formattedDateString = DateTime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
    String bucketname = 'test-salesforce-upload';
    String host = 's3.amazonaws.com';

    String key = credentials.key;
    String secret = credentials.secret;
    String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n'+formattedDateString+'\n\n/'+bucketname+'/'+filename;
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueOf(stringToSign), blob.valueof(secret));
    String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signed;

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
    req.setEndpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+bucketname);
    req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
    req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
    Blob blobBody = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(blobBody);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);
    System.debug(resp);
}
```

The code give 503 error. The actual message in the logs is:

```
DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=Forbidden, StatusCode=403]
```

How can I fix this issue? Feel free to ask for any clarifications. Thanks for your time.

**Edit 1**

I upload a sample file to s3 manually and set its permission to public. Now when I try to access the file in apex using the below code it give 503 error but it works using postman.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Host', 'test-salesforce-upload.s3.amazonaws.com');
    req.setEndpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-salesforce-upload/AWS+Program.docx');

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + res.toString());
    System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
    System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

[image]

Comment: What about the bucket policies in S3 and the CORS configuration? are those setup to accept requests from your instance

Comment: Yes the bucket policies are set. I think the issue might be with the host.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script in one of my classes:

```
public with sharing class AmazonS3Controller {
    public void uploadObject(){

        Blob fileBlob = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        String fileBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob);
        String now = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
        String bucketname = 'emoranbucket';
        String host='emoranbucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
        System.debug('fileBody: ' + fileBody);
        String contentType = 'text/html';
        String fileName = 'text.txt';
        String method = 'PUT';
        String key = '';
        String secret = '';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint('http://' + bucketname + '.' + host + '/' +UserInfo.getUserId() + '/' + fileName);
        req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(fileBody.length()));
        req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', contentType);
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        req.setHeader('Date', now);
        req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read');
        req.setBody(fileBody);

        String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' + contentType + '\n' + now + '\n' +'/' + bucketname + '/' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '/' + fileName;

        String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), Blob.valueOf(secret));
        String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
        String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signed;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
        String decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encodedStringToSign , 'UTF-8');

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + res.toString());
        System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());


    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. First it gave me error that bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com is blocked due to remote settings. After I  have added the bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com in remote settings I get 503 error

Comment: Also this way every time I have to upload to a different bucket I will have to add that bucket to the in the list of all sites in the remote settings